# AzureAD + Dotnet: Is there a way to get the administrator of the user that sends the request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I am making an API in asp.net that is protected using JwtBearerTokens from AzureAd.
When a user creates a resource, i want to add the Id of this user and the users administrator to a custom "owners" field of the resource.
I know I can get an unique identifier for the user sending the request by looking at the "oid" field from the ID-token, but I am unsure how (or if at all possible) i can get the "oid" of the users admin.

Comment: Are you looking for the user's administrator or manager?

Comment: Please let us know if one of the below answers was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_88S3VevVj3uZZlj&Q_CHL=gl
>

Answer (score 0):

A user doesn't have an "Administrator", but does have a Manager in AD. as such, you can use graph api, to pull a user profile and look for the manager endpoint
/users/upn/manager
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD has no per user administrator but manager. The latter is optional thus you will need to [assign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) one first before [querying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) it or you will get a 404 (not found) response status. Optionally you might [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and register a member of an [admin directory role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles). Keep in mind that in order to have the directory roles available they must have been assigned at least one member or you will get, again, a 404 status.

For more information about MS Graph take a look to [Use the Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0), [Authentication and authorization basics for Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts?view=graph-rest-1.0) and the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).